# pointer to character array in c

Tags: c, arrays

Below program gives same output for value `9001`. It should print `9` for first part and `1` for second part. The function `words()` takes correct value as passed and returns appropriate value as desired. But in printing something goes wrong and it doesn't print the value passed by the function.

Thank you for your help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char * words(int n);
const char * twenty[] = { "One ","Two ","Three ","Four ","Five ","Six 
","Seven ","Eight ","Nine ","Ten ","Eleven ","Twelve ",
"Thirteen ","Fourteen ","Fifteen ","Sixteen ","Seventeen ","Eighteen 
","Nineteen ","Twenty " };
const char * thirty[] = { "Thirty ","Fourty ","Fifty ","Sixty ","Seventy 
","Eighty ","Ninty " };

int main() {
    //get input from user to print no to words
    printf("Give no :");
    int x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    char * answer[] = { "","" };
    if (x < 0 || x > 999999) 
        printf("Give no between 1 and 999999\n");
    else {
        if (x / 1000 > 0) {
            answer[0] = words(x / 1000);
            answer[1] = words(x % 1000);
        }
        else 
            answer[0] = words(x % 1000);
        printf("Frist part is : %s\n", answer[0]);
        printf("Second part is : %s\n", answer[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}

char * words(int n) {
    char * ans = "";
    if (n == 0) 
        return ans;
    if (n / 100 > 0) 
        ans = strcat(twenty[n / 100 - 1], "Hundred ");
    if (n % 100 < 21 && n % 100 > 0) 
        ans = strcat(ans, twenty[n % 100 - 1]);
    else{
        if (n % 100>0) 
            ans = strcat(ans, thirty[(n % 100) / 10 - 3]);
        if (n % 10>0) 
            ans = strcat(ans, twenty[`enter code here`(n % 10) - 1]);
    }
    return ans;
};
```

Comment: please post properly indented code.  Also "ninty"

Comment: Please don't use `c++` tag if the code is `c`.

Comment: For 21 you will get a signal 11, because the limits of thirty will exceed.

Comment: Yes, my code is not properly indented and hence a bit difficult to understand. My sincere apology. I shall be very careful next time onward. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `words()` function you cannot do,

```
strcat(ans, ....)
```

or

```
strcat(twenty[n / 100 - 1], ...)
```

The `ans` and elements in `twenty` does not have enough memory to hold that many characters.

One of the way is to allocate buffer for `ans` and use you it to return words. Do not rewrite strings in `twenty[]`.

```
int max_ans_len = 1000;
char *ans = malloc(sizeof(char) * max_ans_len);
...
```

And do not assign return value of `strcat()` to `ans` again. Also make sure you do not write more than `max_ans_len` in it, and free it once its use is done.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers somewhat miss the point as to why you can't append to ans. The fact that there isn't enough space is immaterial. More to the point is the fact that the memory is read only. For instance the assembler generated by gcc 7.2 will look like

```
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string ""
```

rodata - read only data. If you try to write to this then you will get a segmentation fault.

For instance

```
#include <string.h>

void foo()
{
   char *ans = "\0234567890";
   strcat(ans, "string");
}

int main()
{
   foo();
}
```

The 10 bytes pointed to by `ans` are now enough to contain the 7 bytes of the num terminated `"string"`. But this still causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

### 1) Problem with the `char* ans = "";` declaration

There is some misunderstanding, especially inside the `char* words(int n)` function. If we look at the [description of the `strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function, we see that:

> Appends a copy of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by src to
>   the end of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by dest. The
>   character src[0] replaces the null terminator at the end of dest. The
>   resulting byte string is null-terminated.
>
> **The behavior is undefined if**
>   **the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both** **src**
>   **and dest** **and the terminating null character**. The behavior is undefined
>   if the strings overlap. The behavior is undefined if either dest or
>   src is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string.

That's because of `char* ans = "";` inside the `words()` function, which is effectively the same as `char ans[1] = { '\0' };`. There is no way for any word with at least one character to fit in.

Therefore, you should redeclare the `ans` array as follows:

```
char* ans = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
```

Now, we will be able to return `ans` because it is not a local variable, and it also has quite a lot of space (100 characters). Thanks to `calloc()`, it is filled with zeroes - that will work great with `strcat`.

NOTE: You must add `#include <stdlib.h>` for `calloc()` to be available.

### 2) Problem with using element of `const char* twenty[]` array as destination for `strdup`

Second problem is here:

```
ans = strcat(twenty[n / 100 - 1], "Hundred ");
```

Here you try to concatenate `"Hundred "` at the end of the `twenty[n / 100 - 1]` string - I think this is a typo of yours, anyway, it should not be done primarily because the `twenty` array is `const` - it should not be modified.

### 3) Freeing dynamically allocated memory

Finally, we need to free the memory allocated by `calloc()` inside `words()` function. This can be done by adding something like this at the end of `main()` (but before the `return` statement, of course):

```
if (strlen(answer[0]) > 0) {
    free(answer[0]);
}
if (strlen(answer[1]) > 0) {
    free(answer[1]);
}
```

### 4) The result program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* words(int n);
const char* twenty[] = { "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five ", "Six", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine ", "Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ",
    "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ", "Seventeen ", "Eighteen", "Nineteen ", "Twenty " };
const char* thirty[] = { "Thirty ", "Fourty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy", "Eighty ", "Ninty " };

int main()
{
    //get input from user to print no to words
    printf("Give no :");
    int x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    char* answer[] = { "", "" };
    if (x < 0 || x > 999999)
        printf("Give no between 1 and 999999\n");
    else {
        if (x / 1000 > 0) {
            answer[0] = words(x / 1000);
            answer[1] = words(x % 1000);
        } else
            answer[0] = words(x % 1000);
        printf("Frist part is : %s\n", answer[0]);
        printf("Second part is : %s\n", answer[1]);
    }
    if (strlen(answer[0]) > 0) {
        free(answer[0]);
    }
    if (strlen(answer[1]) > 0) {
        free(answer[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}

char* words(int n)
{
    char* ans = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    if (n == 0)
        return ans;
    //if (n / 100 > 0) ans = strcat(twenty[n / 100 - 1], "Hundred ");
    if (n % 100 < 21 && n % 100 > 0)
        ans = strcat(ans, twenty[n % 100 - 1]);
    else {
        if (n % 100 > 0)
            ans = strcat(ans, thirty[(n % 100) / 10 - 3]);
        if (n % 10 > 0)
            ans = strcat(ans, twenty[(n % 10) - 1]);
    }
    return ans;
};
```

I have formatted the result code with `clang-format -style=WebKit main.c`.

And it works!

```
mirek@home:/hyper$ ./main
Give no :9001
Frist part is : Nine 
Second part is : One 
mirek@home:/hyper$
```

Moreover, valgrind reports no memory error:

```
mirek@home:/hyper$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./main
==7605== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7605== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7605== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7605== Command: ./main
==7605== 
Give no :9001
Frist part is : Nine 
Second part is : One 
==7605== 
==7605== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7605==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7605==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,248 bytes allocated
==7605== 
==7605== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7605== 
==7605== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7605== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
mirek@home:/hyper$
```